# Sort() - Would like a good explanation

Tags: javascript, function, sorting

I understand I need to use...

`var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});`

...to sort an array for its MAX value. I've read MDN's documentation on this but I still don't feel as though I really understand what's going on here.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What part of `sort` are you not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the a and b from the anonymous function passed

```
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){console.log('a = '+ a + ' b = ' + b);return b-a});
a = 40 b = 100
a = 40 b = 1
a = 1 b = 5
a = 40 b = 5
a = 1 b = 25
a = 5 b = 25
a = 40 b = 25
a = 1 b = 10
a = 5 b = 10
a = 25 b = 10
[100, 40, 25, 10, 5, 1]
```

so here

1. `b` is 100 and `a` is 40 so `b - a` is positive number so `a` is smaller
2. a is compared to next b which is 1 then b becomes smaller
3. a(previous b) is compared to next b which is 5
   this time a is smaller so a is compared with all the previous ones using similar method
4. Same thing continues till the whole array is sorted

Comment: Note the particular order in which the comparisons are made is dependent upon the internal sort algorithm used and the original position of items in the array - it will not necessarily be the same sequence from one JS implementation to the next.  And, that does not matter to you.  You just provide the comparison algorithm and the internal sort algorithm does the rest.

Comment: NOTE: function should return a positive number if the first value comes before the second, negative if the second one is to come first, and 0 if they are equal.

Answer (score 2):

The `.sort()` function uses an optimized sort algorithm.  By default, it does a lexical comparison.  If you want to use the optimized algorithm, but with some other comparison function such as a numeric comparison or any other type of custom sort, then the one thing you need to tell it is how to compare two values.  Whenever it's trying to compare two values in your array, it will call your custom comparison function and pass each value to you.  You then compare those two values in your own custom way and return value that indicates which value is higher or if the values are equal.  The internal `.sort()` algorithm then uses that info to properly position those two values in relation to one another.

Your custom function returns one of three possibilities, a negative number, zero or a positive number depending upon whether `a < b`, `a === b` or `a > b`.

The function that just does `return b - a` is a very simple reverse numeric sort (highest value first).  If `b > a`, then this will return a number `> 0`.  If `b === a`, then this will return `0`.  And, if `b < a`, this will return a number `< 0` which is exactly what the `.sort()` callback needs to do.

---

If you really only want the maximum value and don't need to actually sort the array, you can simply do this:

```js
var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
var maxPoint = Math.max.apply(Math, points);

// should output
document.write(maxPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method takes an optional argument, a function that defines the sort order. This function compares two values at a time, swapping them if necessary in order to generate the sorted array.

This compare function returns a number which basically controls the sorting order. In your case the function returns the difference between the second arg and the first one which means that if b > a (which is the case of the first 2 elements of your array: 40 and 100), b will be placed first in the resulting array followed by a i.e sort the array descending.

This process of swapping the elements of the array based on the result of the function repeats until no swaps are required. See Wikipedia's bubble sort explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: You can be certain that `sort` does not use bubble sort, it doesn't even "swap" them after comparing.